# Hook into page unload in LWC/Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

In a VF page, I can successfully hook into window.onbeforepageunload, but in LWCs and Lightning Components I am not really finding a way to do this.

In a Lightning Component hosted on a VisualForce page, I put a console.log in the unrender function and preserved my console through navigations. No log showed up when I navigated off the page.

In an LWC hosted on a VisualForce page, I put a console.log in the disconnectedCallback function and did not get any log when I navigated away from the page.

Is there anyway to detect the page changing or closing inside the LWC or Lightning Component and execute some javascript before it happens?

Comment: is  onbeforepageunload a typo? the event is called beforeunload. i quickly tested a vf page and both (addEventlistener & window.onbeforeunload = ) showed me the confirmation dialog on switching a tab after a couple of reloads

Comment: Sorry, yes. Onbeforeunload I meant. But it works fine on a VF page, but my issue is finding out how to do something similar inside an LWC or lightning component, not relying on the beforeunload in the VF page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In both Aura and Web Components, you simply add an event listener to `window` directly.

```
// Aura: controller //
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', helper.beforeUnloadHandler.bind(helper));
}
// Aura: helper //
beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
  console.log('before unload handler has been called.');
}
```

---

```
// LWC
connectedCallback() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler.bind(this));
}

beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
  console.log('before unload handler has been called.');
}
```

All Window events should be supported, but some do not technically make sense (e.g. do not listen for `DOMContentLoaded`, because it will have already fired by the time your component comes in to existence).

I wrote a [WebComponents](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/rVgLg9grXv76T4FD7Pzq/src/app.js) example for LWC.

Note that for Aura, you must wrap your function within a $A.getCallback if you wish to interact with the Aura life cycle (e.g. firing events).

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, but one thing of concern (and it is kind of outside of my original question since I was initially asking about VF hosted components), but in Pure lightning page, the beforeunload never seems to fire when you just switch to a different lightning tab, or even click a lookup link on a record.

Comment: @TylerDahle In LEX, the page never unloads, as it is a Single Page Application. For that use case, we can use [lightning:unsavedChanges](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) instead.

Comment: Does that force a dialog a user has to interact with? I just need to quietly and silently execute JavaScript and let the user be on their way.

Comment: @TylerDahle What's the context for what you're trying to do, exactly? Are they in LEX? A VF page in LEX? Console? There are different solutions to various contexts, and I suppose a few contexts where developers can't do anything. The circumstances at hand change the solution.

Comment: We are just trying to collect usage stats on unload. On VF page it's fine because unload actually works. Or maybe that is just VF pages in classic? But we do have lightning components on lightning pages that suffer from this limitation. Unrender isn't even firing on my component when I tab away in LEX.

Comment: @TylerDahle In a LEX Page, the disconnectedCallback or unrender method would only be called upon destruction of the component; simply changing tabs would not cause this to happen, as the component still exists. Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way out for this situation other than perhaps periodically pinging the server with status updates.

Comment: Yeah I see the rerender MIGHT work for our cases since clicking buttons seems to trigger this for our components. Otherwise we were discussing trying ever 5 seconds or so, which isn't ideal, but might just have to be how it works. Thanks for the info on this!

Comment: The Playground link no longer works.  What's the code in the html file of the LWC that calls onbeforeunload?

Comment: @PaulN Thanks for calling this out. I haven't migrated all of the links from Playground to WebComponents, but I have published all of my examples that were in Playground in [this repo](https://github.com/brianmfear/playground-examples). I'll build a WC link for this, it should be a quick copy-paste. ... and done.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ah ha! Great, I see that you added the event to standard window object!  Thank you!

Comment: Note that I needed to bind my beforeUnloadHandler to "this" in order for it to work correctly:
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.beforeUnloadHandler.bind(this));
But this did exactly what I needed. (And, DUH, I see that you have put that in the code above already too.)