# DisconnectedCallback in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom

I want to do some DML operation when my lwc is removed from the DOM, so can anyone please confirm if disconnected callback will run on all below scenario

1. on close tab.
2. on browser close.
3. got disconnected from internet.
4. shut down the machine.

I know this might seem a silly question, but it is really important in my case.

Comment: I have tried all these on the playground but did not work, not sure about the SF platform(I doubt, also there is not enough documentation about `disconnectedCallback()`). Also in 3rd the point you won't be able to update the record if there is no internet connection.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 7):

No, disconnectedCallback only works when the app is still loaded and the component is unloaded.

> on close tab.
>
> on browser close.
>
> shut down the machine.

Use onunload to do any last second reactions. Note that the best you can probably do is store something in localStorage so you can pick up where you left off.

> got disconnected from internet.

Use `onconnect` to figure out when you're back online (you can't save while offline).

Comment: That's awesome!!, I could not find this in the docs. Can you share the link, please?

Comment: @rahulgawale You won't find this in the LWC docs, as this is just standard browser behavior. Try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) instead. onunload and onconnect are both in the docs.

Comment: Thank you Brain for your response, would you please suggest if is there any way I can get information on how many users are currently using an LWC page within an org?

Comment: Suggested similar question and additional information: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269861/hook-into-page-unload-in-lwc-lightning-component

Answer (score 5):

I checked this example, the `disconnectedCallback` gets called only when the parent component unloads it.

[Check this playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/lmnyLATdTmfjor6GJOdE)

I have added `if:true` on the child component which is getting changed via the checkbox on the parent. So whenever I uncheck the checkbox. The disconnected callback is getting called. But not when the events mentioned by you.

Comment: Thank you Rahul for your response, useful information.