# LWC detect page navigation in Community?

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, navigation

I have a custom Lightning Web Component that is placed on a page in a Customer Community.  Community users use the LWC to enter and save data.

I would like the LWC to detect when the user tries to navigate to another page in the community (e.g. by clicking on a navigation menu tab, etc) so I can warn them about unsaved changes in the LWC.

I've read several posts about setting an event listener for `beforeunload` like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269861/hook-into-page-unload-in-lwc-lightning-component) and [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308838/how-can-i-prevent-closer-refresh-of-a-tab-in-lwc/308871#308871).

However, my code only detects when the user tries to reload the browser page.  It doesn't detect when the user clicks on a nav menu tab to go to a different community page.

Is there anyway for an LWC to detect a page navigation in Community?

Here's my LWC JS code snippet.  Note I'm testing multiple approaches:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler.bind(this));
}

connectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler.bind(this));
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler.bind(this));
}

beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    console.log("in beforeUnloadHandler");
    this.showToast(
        "Success",
        "in beforeUnloadHandler",
        "success"
    );
}

showToast(theTitle, theMessage, theVariant) {
    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: theTitle,
        message: theMessage,
        variant: theVariant,
        messageTemplate: "{0}",
        messageTemplateData: [theMessage]
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For now, at least, you can't do this with LWC, as far as I can tell. Instead, use an Aura component and use [lightning:unsavedChanges](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) to block navigation away from your component. You can avoid rewriting your LWC by wrapping it in an Aura component to add the extra logic.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately `unsavedChanges` isn't supported in Community.  Looks like we can't do what we want, for now.