# LWC Event to Catch internal Salesforce Navigation

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, lwc-dom

**My Question** :
Are there any events which checks whether user navigates to which navigation menu right now ?

**For Example** :
When I am at **Case** Record Page and my **LWC** is placed there,
So If I switch to **Account** or **Contact** Records Page I need to **save** the data in the LWC!

So I am looking for event like these :

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadHandler.bind(this));
window.addEventListener('offline', this.checkDisconnectTime.bind(this));
window.addEventListener('online', this.checkDisconnectTime.bind(this));
```

Comment: Please check this one https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269861/hook-into-page-unload-in-lwc-lightning-component

Answer (score 2):

For LWC, use [CurrentPageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation). You'll receive a wire event each time the parameters/state changes. Note that you'll need to capture the state when the Case is visited, because the navigation event only tells you where you're headed to, not where you've been.

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference) handlePageReference(pageReference) {
  // do something with pageReference.state
}
```

Comment: can you please explain lil bit more?  actually i store something in Custom Object when some on case record page and if someone navigate from that page. for example. i'm at case record details page, and i click on account or contact object in navigation bar than what i left behind in case record page that should be save in salesforce.

Comment: @FahimKhan You would check if the user arrives at the case page, then initialize your custom object data. When the user leaves the page, you'll know you're elsewhere, and you can save that data.

Comment: is this correct?

@wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

        handlePageReference(pageRef) {
            if (pageRef.state.c__pageName === 'case') {
              // Initialize custom object data
              console.log("On Case Page Rightnow.");
            } else {
              // Save custom object data
              this.stop();
              this.createSLADataFromJS();
              this.reason = 'Salesforce Navigation Change Log';
              this.createRecordSlaTimer();
              this.stime = "00:00:00";
            }
          }

Comment: my console log goes every time to ELSE part. even if i am at case record page. what is the reason? @sfdxfox

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if there is a pure LWC version of this, but in aura you can use the `forceCommunity:routeChange` event.

Aura Main

```html
<aura:handler
  event="forceCommunity:routeChange"
  action="{!c.handleRouteChange}"
/>
<lightning:messageChannel
  type="CommunityMessageService__c"
  aura:id="communityMessageService"
  scope="APPLICATION"
/>
```

Aura Controller JS

```js
handleRouteChange: function (component, event, helper) {
  // Publish LMS message to LWC
  component.find('communityMessageService').publish({
    name: 'navigate',
    payload: {
      location: document.location,
    },
  })
}
```

If you're within an Aura based context, you could use Lightning Message Service to communicate this back to your LWC component.

If you're within a purely LWC context (LWR Communities), you might have to try another way.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i want event in lwc. actually i store something in case record page when someone navigate from that page. for example. i'm at case record details page, and i click on account or contact object in navigation bar than what i left behind in case record page that should be save in salesforce. @lu_ke____

Comment: This most likely won't work as expected with internal Salesforce. As mentioned, works best within Aura based communities. I got mixed results with `CurrentPageReference` in communities. Would recommend using [CurrentPageReference.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) mentioned in the other answer for pure LWC.